# Make date change permanent in EC2

Tags: date, time, amazon-ec2, aws

How can I manually set date and time to future in EC2 instance and make it permanent, so it won't reset after reboot ?

I can change date using this command:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-time "2017-12-09 16:00:00"
$ timedatectl 
      Local time: Sat 2017-12-09 16:00:01 UTC
  Universal time: Sat 2017-12-09 16:00:01 UTC
        RTC time: Sat 2017-12-09 16:00:02
       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

OS on EC2:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

What else should I do to make this permanent ?

The purpose of this adjustment is to set the date to future, so I can test few things.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Updated the question with OS.

Comment: I wrote an answer I feel will meet your needs better than what you asked. Tell me if that doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

You can setup `ntp` for your instance.

Install the package `ntp`

```
apt-get/yum install ntp
```

Edit the configuration

```
nano /etc/ntp.conf
```

Add an `ntp` server to the config file, depending on the country you live in find the appropriate server(Just google "your_country_name ntp server"). Depending on your OS, the configuration file might have server instead of pool or vise versa.

```
server/pool 0.ntp_server_in_your_country iburst
```

Restart and enable the `ntpd` daemon.

```
systemctl enable ntpd && systemctl start ntpd
```

`ntp` will make sure you have the correct time every time you restart the server, that is because it synchronizes the time with that of the server.

Comment: This will sync the time but I need to manually set the time to future and keep it that way, so I can test some things.

Answer (score 0):

[Libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime), if preloaded with your application can add offsets or set specific times as the current time. It may work better than setting a system wide change.

It can also set a system wide time if you need, though.

Basic usage is:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="2017-12-09 16:00:00" commandyouneed
```